# Glassfish - multi-instance EAR application

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ear

Our CMS is written as JavaEE application and distributed as EAR file. Now, I'd like to run multiple instances of this application, each for one customer running on it's own virtual server. What is the best aproach to achieve this? Is it possible to run the same application with same war contexts more times on different virtual servers in glassfish? Thank you

Comment: Should be possible. It sounds that you should ask this question on ServerFault as it's not directly programming related.

Comment: Google is your friend. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggncs.html